# IIS7 Rest, send a "request received" response before data is sent?

Tags: http, rest, iis-7

I was hoping someone could push me in the right direction here.

We have an issue with our android tablets (we have traced it down to firmware on the tablets, and the developers from the company are putting a fix together, but that may take months to make it to us) which is caused by our IIS7 server not responding to a request fast enough.

We have a get method that takes 1 parameter and it will execute a stored proc and return that information.  The stored proc takes 3 seconds to execute (we can not improve this performance).  because of the 3 second delay, the tablet malfunctions.

What I imagine to be happening is that IIS does not send anything back until it starts to send the data from the stored proc.

Is there something I can do to get IIS to send some sort of acknowledgement that the request was received? (and to wait for data?)

Comment: 3 seconds is a *very* short timeout on waiting for a data response from the server, I have had long-polling scripts in browser->PHP that will still work without sending back any data for 5 minutes+. Regardless of that - could you send the headers immediately and wait 3 seconds on sending the body, or does the stored procedure affect any of the headers? E.g. do you need to send a `content-length:`? If you have the client send `connection: close` then a `content-length:` should be unnecessary in the response since the server will close the connection.

Comment: I agree 3 seconds is a short length (the tablet manufacture as acknowledged there is a serious bug here).  Ill have to look more into how to do what you suggest (and to understand how to test that).  I guess Ill also have to learn http protocol to understand what is going on?

Comment: `I guess Ill also have to learn http protocol to understand what is going on?` - That would definitely be a good start... ;-)